# OS X provisioning profiles wont sync

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

Last week I added a new app id and created a provisioning profile for it. I went into XCode 5 to refresh my profiles so that the profile I added in the member center would sync to my xcode. This had the result of removing all my OSX profiles. All my IOS ones show up fine. I tried manually downloading the profiles and installing them but that did not help. Because of this I can no longer build my OSX apps because they complain about the provisioning profile being invalid. I have since upgraded my xcode to 6 but the problem persists. I started a new OSX app and it looks like there is now an automatic provisioning profile. Does this mean I no longer have to mess with provisioning profiles? Is this only for osx or does it apply to ios also. When I submit this new app without a specific provisioning profile will the app store reject it? What the heck is going on?

Comment: Did you try downloading and installing provisioning profile manually?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will update the question to include that info.